# PC keeps shutting down. Exhausted my knowledge

Tags: windows-10, shutdown

I need some serious help here because I am lost as all heck.

I decommissioned my old PC and got some new parts, was running fine when I set it up, everything seemed normal. Temps, clocks, power, all in order. Could run and play on it for several hours. Even tried the Asus overclocking feature to have it gently knock things up a notch after I was sure the cooling worked. Then I went to see my father over the weekend and when I got back yesterday stuff started.
The thing kept turning off randomly. Screen goes idle, fans turn up a bit, 10-20 seconds later the whole thing shuts down. In Windows, in safe mode, load, no load, didnt matter. NOTHING related shows up in the eventlog, just the "unexpected shutdown" warning.

Tried reinstalling the OS, flashing new BIOS version, disassembled almost the entire thing, put one component after another in, switched out RAMs, tried without GPU, tried several BIOS settings etc., all the while stresstesting each step with benchmarks, Prime95 and memtest.

After about 4 hours it seems like everything was back to normal, I had re-assembled the entire thing and freshly installed the OS, made sure I got all the drivers and left most stuff at default in the BIOS. So I thought I was safe. Ran a few more benchmarks, gamed for a few hours, all coolio.

Then, today, just fifteen minutes ago, it all happened again. Now it even happens in BIOS as I was checking settings. I am honestly left clueless, it CANT be heat, BIOS tells me everything is alright around 30°C.

Running the following specs:

ASUS Maximus VII Hero

Intel i7 4790K

BeQuiet 750W PSU

4x4GB 1600 DDR3 RAM

GTX 970 with single monitor

m.2 Samsung Evo 950 as boot medium

one more SSD and two more HDDs

Noctua NH-D14 fan

chassis has like 4 fans extra, all are turning

BIOS version is 2.16.1240

I am SO lost as to what it could be. When I fixed it yesterday I thought it might be related to Voltage because Core 2 keeps swinging between 1.04 and 1.2 Volts but google said not it.

I flipped up CPU-z and squeezed this report out of it. Maybe this helps with finding the error(s).

pastebin.com/gKabU7cT

Please Help!

What I tried:

- Disassemble as much as possible. RAM out, HDDs/SSDs out, GPU out, unneeded fans out. Error persisted.
- Try out other components. Different PSU, different RAM. Error persisted.
- Tried reapplying the thermal paste and even a different Fan. Error persisted.
- Reinstall OS and reset MoBo (CMOS) and BIOS. Error persisted.
- Flash new BIOS version. Error persisted.
- Buy a powerplug with overvoltageprotection and EMI/RFI filter. Error persisted.
- Set up PC in a different room. Error persisted.
- Set the PC up in the office. Error went away. Could've been just random luck.
- Tried out with a UPS. Showed stable voltage. Everything well. Tried without again to confirm results, error still not visible. Result: Test useless.

All the while I have been stress testing like crazy, making sure the PC was sweating and not just lazing about. Which didn't really matter anyway since the error happened regardless of load, even in BIOS.

Comment: Thank you for asking this question, @user610876. Sorry to hear it was bad news after the diagnostics. I'd like to see you keep the SU rep for the trouble; over the next day or so how about you or I or some user edit the diagnostics and results discussed here into the question and roll the reasoning and result into an answer? Maybe there's a dupe on the site, but if not Rohit kr's answer is evidence that preserving what you've been through will be useful to others.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41791/discussion-on-question-by-user610876-pc-keeps-shutting-down-exhausted-my-knowle).

Comment: Please note that Super User has a fairly strict policy on potentially-offensive language. I removed a certain word from your question, so it's all good now, but keep that in mind in the future.

Comment: "and got some new parts" Can you indicate which parts were new? Sometimes, RMA is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing this problem and my is off for three days for the same issue.

After searching three days on the web, i found this problem is related to hardware not the software.

In beginning I tried reinstalling os, reset and update bios and finally opened case and pulled everything out and reassembled but nothing happened. Even all hardware tests on drives,ram and other things are om and temp is 40c normal.

It was shutdown while working last time and now it's not even loading os. Turn on and off repeatedly.

I contacted motherboard manufacturer and they are saying to replace psu (amps). Still I am waiting for another response.